# Changing a dictionary value from other file

Tags: python

So I have this module **player.py** which is a class of a player, this class gets instantiated at the start of my game creating a player object with **hp and dmg** on my other module **dicts.py** I have some sort of skills stored in a dictionary as following:

```
new_dmg = 0

Skill = {
    'double_dmg': {
    'dmg': new_dmg * 2
   }
}
```

and in the **player.py** I set new_dmg in the `__init__` function

```
def __init__(self, hp, dmg):
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.hp = hp
    dicts.new_dmg = dmg
```

however, it seems like the skill dmg will be set to `0 * 2` before my player class is instantiated which happens at the very start of the game, I believe it is an easy task, but I am not able to grasp how to do it even though I spent alot of time with python. Any explanation/workaround will be pretty helpful <3

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to do what you're asking. You could just put the skill dict in a class and instantiate that class in the player class, you could do something similar with a function that returns the skills dict, or you could patch over the skills dict directly, and I could go on, but those would be the most sane approaches. You're essentially asking to "fix your design" (where there are 100s of ways to "fix" it), but that's not really particularly on topic for SO.

Comment: well I know I could solve the problem, class/a function returning the dict but I am not sure why is the code in the **dicts.py** is executed before my **player.py** and how can I change that order, any links would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like the confusion is stemming around how Python instantiates modules and/or how expressions are evaluated. When you do:

```
new_dmg = 0

Skill = {
    'double_dmg': {
    'dmg': new_dmg * 2
   }
}
```

upon import, the `dict` called `Skill` will look like this:

```
{'double_dmg': {'dmg': 0}}
```

That's because we generate a *new* integer `0 * 2`, (substitute in `new_dmg`'s value), which evaluates to `0`. Integers are immutable, so when we have an expression that evaluates to an integer, a *new* integer is created. This means we don't maintain a reference to `new_dmg` inside of the `Skill` `dict`, so changing `new_dmg` will *not* change `Skill`.

To test this, just put it in a file and run it in your Python interpreter:

```
>>> import dicts
>>> dicts.Skill
{'double_dmg': {'dmg': 0}}
>>> dicts.new_dmg = 500
>>> dicts.Skill
{'double_dmg': {'dmg': 0}}
```

Note that the `Skill` didn't change, because again, it's defined and evaluated *on import* and integers are an immutable type. So changing `new_dmg` will *not* change anything in `Skill`. If you want to change it, just do it directly:

```
>>> def set_double_damage(new_dmg):
...   dicts.Skill['double_dmg']['dmg'] = 2 * new_dmg
...
>>> set_double_damage(500)
>>> dicts.Skill
{'double_dmg': {'dmg': 1000}}
```

or, make it so that your dicts class can be *instantiated* with a damage value. There are innumerable ways to tackle your particular issue.

Comment: Man thanks so much! I noticed this behaviour but I had no clue why does it follow this specific order, I will stick to the `set_dmg` function, Thanks again this was  pretty helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because of the order of two events:

1. `Skill` definition (it happens when you first import `dicts` module where `Skill` is defined).
2. execution of the `__init__` (it happens then you create the object of the class)

The way the program is structured you can't do #2 before #1 because `__init__` uses `new_dmg` that is defined in the `dicts` so `dicts` must be imported first into `player` which implies execution of the `dicts` module before `__init__` have any chance to update `dicts.new_dmg`.

Comment: Oh, That is what I missed, I need to restructure my project so it goes in my desired flow, thx mate!